# Properly extending/overriding a library Activity, effectively replacing it in a new project?

Tags: android, android-activity, overriding, extend

I have Library Project A, and child project B. The only difference in B is that a single activity needs to have additional code (for example, for ads)

I know I can just copy A.Activity to B and add code, but if I change code in A, it will not be in B, so this is not an option.

How do I extend A.Activity into B.Activity and add a little code, while keeping it in the place in the manifest (So pushing a button in B.Activity 1, I go to B.Activity 2(which extends from A.Activity)

Detailed scenario:

In project A, when clicking a button in FirstActivity, I go to SecondActivity. I want to override SecondActivity, when in project B, I click on FirstActivity (which is the same one as from A) I go to SecondActivity, which is overridden/extended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found extending activity classes from library projects to be cumbersome and to eventually lead to problems in larger projects. Maybe I'm doing it wrong!

Instead I put all the required functionality into the library project and use a configuration resource (boolean flag for example) to determine whether to enable this functionality or not.

The default configuration is in the library project and then I just override it in xml in the child project.

Comment: Hmm. This sounds like a pretty viable workaround. I like the idea, however I'm not going to mark it as an answer just yet, since it is more a workaround than an answer.

Comment: Sure - I ran into exactly the problems you described (the library project doesn't know about the extended activity...so how do you launch it, etc.) - it just got very messy and convoluted. Now I do it all this way, it seems cleaner to me.

Answer (score 2):

In your child/non-lib project create a new activity (lets call it the child activity) which extends from the activity in the lib project (the parent). Then override the method(s) you want to modify.

In the manifest for the child project you will need to add the child activity and (i presume) make it the launch activity by giving it the appropriate intent filter.

If it is not the launch activity then you probably also have the problem of the intent in library project trying to launch the standard (non-overridden) version of the Activity. I have overcome this before using a sort of 'dynamic' intent system whereby instead of hard coding the class type for the intent, I get it from the Application object which returns a type.

e.g

In Library Project:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private void launchOverideableActivity(){

    MyApp app = (MyApp) getApplication();
    Intent i = new Intent(this, app.getIntentClassType());
    startActivity(i);
}}
```

And override the application object so you can supply this dynamic class type:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

public Class getIntentClassType(){
    return MainActivity.class;
}}
```

Then in your child project, extend your activity and do your custom work. But also override the application object from the library project and override your method but return your overridden activity class type:

```
public class OveriddenApp extends MyApp {

@Override
public Class getIntentClassType() {
    return MyOveriddenActivity.class;
}}
```

Extending activities from library project like this is a bit clunky but in the long run it does allow clearer code separation so this little bit of coding overhead is worth it in my opinion.

I'd love to know if there is a more elegant way to do this...

Comment: Nope, not the launch activity. I tried extending it already; I can easily add code and whatnot, but I can't properly use it when going from FirstActivity to SecondActivity.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. So it takes the activity based on the application instead of hardcoded package. But now my problem is: My child project activity cannot have the same name as the library activity. So I can't have it refer to the same activity name somehow (I get an error). Eclipse thinks I want to extend the activity from itself. Edit: I think I fixed that problem by using the full package name for the 'extends activity'.

Comment: Yes using the full package name should resolve this but I would give your child activity a different name to it's parent for clarity personally.

Comment: @DeanWild I late now, but is it possible to extending a class can also be determined on the basis of runtime. like you said in overriding a application object.